# Is there any meaning/use to the weird floating dialog when pressing 'o' in VA-11 HALL-A?

Tags: va-11-hall-a

I just started playing VA-11 HALL-A and accidentally pressed the <kbd>O</kbd> key and some weird floating dialog showed up on my screen.

[image: Weird floating dialog]

What does it represent and does this have any impact on the game? Or is this just a easter egg?

Comment: I would also like to know in what world does "DROP A COW" become a meme? :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text is similar to how comments work on Nico Nico Douga, if I remember correctly. As for why that's in the game, not knowing exactly how far you are in it, I'm just going to say "keep playing until Friday ingame" and you'll get better context on that.

> You'll have a customer by the name of "Streamer-chan" who streams her life 24/7. Comments like that appear constantly, even while you've got the recipe menu up.

One more thing: if you're playing the Steam release of the game, once achievements get fixed (at the time of this answer - version 1.1.0.1 - they're not working at all), try that again.

Comment: update 1.1.0.2 is out now, and it has fixed the achievements. Incidentally, other keys you might be interested in for similar effects are I, K, L, and P. (For more practical keyboard keys, Q, W, E, R, and T all add ingredients to your drink)